# Area of triangles inside quadrilateral.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, area, quadrilateral

[image]

It seems to wrong statement but how can we prove it? Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you create a quadrilateral where this is not true?

Comment: got it. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can-not prove it because it's wrong in the general.

But we can get any quadrilaterals with this property.

Indeed, let $S_{\Delta AOB}=a,$  $S_{\Delta COB}=b,$  $S_{\Delta COD}=c$ and $S_{\Delta AOd}=d,$

Thus, $$\frac{d}{a}=\frac{DO}{BO}=\frac{c}{b},$$ which gives
$$ac=bd.$$
Now, let $a>d$.

Thus, $b>c$ and
$$(a+c)^2=(b+d)^2$$ or
$$a^2+2ac+c^2=b^2+2bd+d^2$$ or
$$a^2-2ac+c^2=b^2-2bd+d^2$$ or
$$(a-c)^2=(b-d)^2$$ or
$$(a-c+b-d)(a-c-b+d)=0$$ or
$$a-c=b-d$$ and since $$a+c=b+d,$$ we obtain:
$$a=b$$ and $$c=d.$$
Id est, in our quadrilateral $O$ is a mid-point of $AC$

or by the same way we can show that $O$ is a mid-point of $BD$ (if $a>b$, for example).

Comment: thank you. In a general quadrilateral if O is not a midpoint ,statement will not hold.